# Append a value to the front of a list in lisp

Tags: list, append, scheme, lisp, push

Tryin to write a single lisp/scheme expression to insert the new value 'z into the beginning of the list `'(a b)` to produce `'(z a b)`.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of `push`, `append`, `define` and `insert`.  The errors I am getting are *variable is unbound* or *wrong number of variables*.

This is for a class.

Comment: I think you are looking for `cons` or `push`. You should show us the code you have so far, so we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: (push '(a b) '(z))

Comment: Common Lisp or Scheme?

Comment: It's nice that you wrote which error messages were displayed, but we can't really help you fixing your code without seeing it. There are different possibilities which are common beginner mistakes but without more details its hard to tell. Please edit the question.

Comment: Also `(cons 'z '(a b)) ; => (z a b)` so unless you are after maintaining a stack that is the right way 